# Mysql sorting issue with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this

```
d 1
b 3
a 5
c 2
c 4
c 6
```

when I write `SELECT DISTINCT c1 FROM table ORDER BY c2` It take 6 form c2 for c value and return;

```
d
b
a
c
```

but I want it return

```
d
c
b
a
```

How can I do that?

**Edit:**
Actually c2 is date column.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT c1 FROM table GROUP BY c1 ORDER BY MIN(c2)`

Comment: Good point sir, it is still a bit early for my brain this morning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

INSTEAD OF

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1 FROM table ORDER BY c
```

TRY

```
SELECT c1, MIN(c2) AS minC2 FROM table GROUP BY c1 ORDER BY c2
```

Comment: thats did not work because actually c2 is date created with timestamp type.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c1
FROM
(SELECT c1, c2 FROM tbl GROUP BY c1 ORDER BY c1, c2) X
ORDER BY c2
```

Making use of MySQL ordered GROUP BY collection, the inner query will only pick the minimum c2 record without specifically using MIN.  The outer query then sorts properly by the (min) c2 value.